# MATLAB: Return the number of discrete points under a graph

Tags: matlab, geometry, discrete-mathematics

I need to write a function that will take a radius r and return an integer number of discrete points strictly within a circle of radius r, centered at the origin. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show us. A representative image would be nice also :)

Comment: I don't have much in terms of code at the moment.  But my thinking is that I would have a range of integers from -R to R representing each x and y, and then need to count the number of coordinates (x,y) which satisfy x^2 + y^2 < R^2.  I guess I'm just not sure how to concatenate the two arrays into a representative coordinate and then count the number of those satisfying the equation.

Comment: @user2049004 - You've got the right thinking.  You just needed to figure out the right function to generate your co-ordinates :) See my post.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you haven't showed us any attempts to solving your code, this is a nice exercise that I wouldn't mind tackling.  What you can do first is generate a square grid of co-ordinates centered at the origin that span between `-r` and `+r`.  Bear in mind that the spacing between each point in your 2D grid is 1, if I'm interpreting your question right.

Once you do this, you can find those locations where the Euclidean distance is strictly less than `r`, then return the number of points where this condition is satisfied.  To generate the square grid of points, use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html).  Assuming that you've defined your radius in `r`, you would do the following code:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-r:r, -r:r);
x = x(:);
y = y(:);
num_points = sum(x.^2 + y.^2 < r^2);
```

The `x = x(:);` and `y = y(:);` are important.  This turns the 2D grid for each `x` and `y` into single column vectors.  Specifically, it takes each column of your matrix, and stacks all of them from top to bottom to make a single vector.   It makes analysis easier.  The reason why is because if we tried to use [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) on a 2D matrix, it can only sum in one direction.  You can either sum over all of the columns individually, or sum over all of the rows individually.  Since you want to sum over the entire array, you can either call `sum` twice, or convert your 2D grid into a stack of 1D arrays.  I opted for the second approach because I think it's cleaner, but some people don't mind chaining `sum` calls together too... it's just  a style preference.

Once you do this, we simply check to see whether the Euclidean distance is less than the radius.  Note that I'm calculating the Euclidean squared distance to avoid computing the square root.  It'll save in computation time.  We then sum over all instances and this will define how many points that fall within the radius.

As an example, supposing our radius was `r = 2`.  This is what our `meshgrid` of points would look like:

```
r = 2;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-r:r, -r:r)

x =

    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -2    -1     0     1     2

y =

    -2    -2    -2    -2    -2
    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
```

For each co-ordinate in our 2D grid, we have an `(x,y)` pair associated at each point.  The final number of points we get is:

```
num_points = 

 9
```

This makes sense as the points that are strictly less than 2 should only be the 3 x 3 block that is centered at the origin.  If you want to be sure, let's visualize what the grid looks like before you convert the co-ordinates into 1D vectors:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-r:r, -r:r);
disp(x.^2 + y.^2 < r^2);

 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

Locations that are `1` denote `true`, which means that this co-ordinate satisfies it being strictly less than `r`.  Locations that are `0` denote `false`, which means that they're outside.  The last part of the algorithm is to sum over all of this array, which gives us 9 and that's how many points are strictly within `r`.

---

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just as an approach:

- define a square matrix that would fit the discrete points
- define a function/condition if the matrix point would be (strictly) within the circle
- count the number of true values

Good luck, and if you have problems somewhere, feel free to modify the post.

Comment: I was literally typing out my solution as you put this in lol.  I decided to solve it anyway as it was a good mental exercise for me.  Nice going anyway!

Comment: If I had matlab at home, I would have done this too ;)